# Rcpp max of vector except one element

Tags: r, rcpp

In `Rcpp` I want to find the maximum of a vector, but I want to omit one element.

I have working code, but I'm sure my approach is quite bad as it involves the full copy of the vector.  Is there a much better way to accomplish what I want?

In R:

```
vec <- 1:10
ele <- 3
max(vec[-ele])
```

My (terrible) version in Rcpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double my_fun(NumericVector vec, int ele) {
    NumericVector vec_no_ele = clone(vec);
    vec_no_ele.erase(ele);
    return max(vec_no_ele);
}
```

Comment: Save the value you want to omit in a temp variable. Set that element to zero or some small value or the same as another value in the vector. Compute the max. Reset the element from the temp variable?

Comment: Thanks!  I guess a related idea would be to `.erase(ele)`, take the max, and then re-`.insert(ele)`.  Any idea if this erase-max-reinsert approach would be horribly inefficient?

Comment: In general you want to avoid copies if you can, and @Spacedman's approach works without a copy --> likely to win for large number of observations, or many repeated calls.

Comment: Note that `NumericVector` is not a dynamic array, hence any `erease()` and `insert()` will trigger copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, `max` is implemented as a humble for loop.  You shouldn't shy away from for loops in c++ since there is much less overhead compared to R.  In this case, a for loop does significantly better than using the built in:

```
// Coatless answer:
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double max_no_copy(NumericVector vec, int ele) {
  double temp = vec[ele-1];
  vec[ele-1] = vec[0];
  double result_max = max(vec);
  vec[ele-1] = temp;
  return result_max;
}

// humble for loop
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double max_except_for(NumericVector vec, int ele) {
  int vs = vec.size();
  double res = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<vs; i++) {
    if( i == ele-1 ) continue;
    if(vec[i] > res) res = vec[i];
  }
  return res;
}
```

R side:

```
x <- rnorm(1e8)
x[1000] <- 1e9
microbenchmark(max_except_for(x, 1000), max_no_copy(x, 1000), times=5)

Unit: milliseconds
                    expr       min        lq     mean    median       uq       max neval cld
 max_except_for(x, 1000)  87.58906  93.56962  92.5092  93.59754  93.6262  94.16361     5  a 
    max_no_copy(x, 1000) 284.46662 292.57627 296.3772 296.78390 300.5345 307.52455     5   b


identical(max_except_for(x, 1000), max_no_copy(x, 1000)) # TRUE
```

Comment: Great answer.  One modification is necessary though:  notice that `max_except_for( c(-1, -2, -3), 1)` returns zero!  A solution is to initialize `res` as an element of `vec`, as I did in my answer on this page: `int idx = (ele > 0) ? ele-1 : ele+1; double res = vec[idx]`

Answer (score 1):

@Spacemen is suggesting the following approach in comments:

> Save the value you want to omit in a temp variable. Set that element to zero or some small value or the same as another value in the vector. Compute the max. Reset the element from the temp variable.

This would be implemented like so:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double max_no_copy(NumericVector vec, int ele) {
  double temp = vec[ele];

  // Use a value already in vector
  vec[ele] = vec[0];

  // Find max value
  double result_max = max(vec);

  // Remove NA value
  vec[ele] = temp;

  return result_max;
}
```

Test:

```
vec <- 1:10
ele <- 2 # C++ indices start at 0 not 1. So, subtract.

max_no_copy(vec, ele)
# [1] 10
```

Benchmark to be added later...

Comment: The only edge case this might not handle is if the vector is of length one, and that's the element to remove from the vector. `max(1[-1])` is `-Inf` with a warning in R.

Comment: Agreed. This was a quick implementation based off of your comment above. I'm not making any assertions here in a similar vein to what was originally posted _R_ code.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @coatless is great and builds on the other generous commenters above.  However, it can be further generalized.  @coatless uses the value in `vec[0]` as the placeholder for the value to be omitted, but this fails when the value to be omitted is element 0!

Here's a slightly generalized solution, where I use the adjacent element to `ele` as the placeholder, and I check that `ele` is in the index of `vec` and that `vec.length()` is greater than 1:

```
// calculate the max of a vector after omitting one element
double max_except(NumericVector vec, int ele) {
    if (vec.length() == 1) stop("vec too short");
    if (ele < 0 | ele > vec.length()-1) stop("ele out of range");
    double temp = vec[ele];
    int idx = (ele > 0) ? ele-1 : ele+1;
    vec[ele] = vec[idx];
    double res = max(vec);
    vec[ele] = temp;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Two quick remarks: 1. the solution given was implemented off of @spacedman’s comment that seeked to accomplish largely the same as the initial R code. 2. the aforementioned solution did not make any assertions regarding inputs. This variant does.

Comment: Hey @coatless James - I wasn't trying to snag your points.  You did a faithful implementation of of spacedman's comment.  I just wanted to "accept" an answer that would be the most useful to future readers with my same question.  Feel free to update your post, I'll delete mine, and I'll mark your as accepted. (Comment here when you've done so, so that I get notified!) Cheers, -Dan

Comment: no need. I'm not motivated by points. I just wanted to emphasize a few corrections to points raised in the first paragraph. Great to hear everything worked out for you in the end!